# C# Converting SQL string from \n to \r\n

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble with an MVC project. I have some data stored in MS SQL that I collect server side and display in a form using a view model. One property of my view model is a string with a max length of 255.

If the string contains a \n character without a \r before it, when I collect the value in C# and display it on the form, a \r character is added automatically. If I debug, the string stored in SQL as "Test\n\nTest" comes out unchanged into a C# string, but after putting this in an input or textarea, inspecting the html of the rendered page, the string becomes "Test\r\n\r\nTest".

This causes problems, when for example the SQL string is close to the max length of 255. Sometimes the additional \r characters push the string length above the 255 limit, meaning the form will no-longer save. This is very confusing for users.

My solution so far is to remove all \r characters just before saving to SQL. But this feels like a very poor solution. Can anyone suggest a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
string newStr = oldStr.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
```

For more info look here: *String.Replace Method (String, String)* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx